# Pytorch tensor get the index of the element with specific values?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

I have two tensores, tensor a and tensor b.

I want to get all indexes of values in tensor b.

For example.

```
a = torch.Tensor([1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5])
```

```
b = torch.Tensor([1,2,4])
```

I want the index of `1, 2, 4` in tensor a. I can do this by the following code.

```py
a = torch.Tensor([1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5])
b = torch.Tensor([1,2,4])
mask = torch.zeros(a.shape).type(torch.bool)
print(mask)
for e in b:
    mask = mask + (a == e)
    print(mask)
```

How can I do it without `for`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

As @[zaydh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2780803/zaydh) kindly pointed out in the comments, since PyTorch `1.10`, `isin()` and `isinf()`(and many other numpy equivalents) are available as well, thus you can simply do:

```py
torch.isin(a, b)
```

which would give you :

```
Out[4]: tensor([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False])
```

### Old answer:

Is this what you want? :

```py
np.in1d(a.numpy(), b.numpy())
```

will result in :

```
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False])
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. Can I do it in PyTorch(do not change tensor to NumPy array)?

Comment: Pytorch does not implement `in1d`, and thereshouldnt be any issues using t his in pytorch. what is it that is bugging you here? the numpy versions also use the underlying data so if you are concerned about the copying , etc there is none!

Comment: By the way, starting with `torch` 1.10, `isin` has native support so you should not need to do the conversion to `numpy` if you use that version or later.

Comment: @ZaydH Thanks for the update, added the new info to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just do not want to use a for loop, you can just use list comprehension:

```
mask = [a[index] for index in b]
```

If do not even want to use the "for" word, you can always convert the tensors to numpy and use numpy indexing.

```
mask = torch.tensor(a.numpy()[b.numpy()])
```

UPDATE

Might have misunderstood your question. In that case, I would say the best way to achieve this is through list comprehension. (Slicing will probably not achieve this.

```
mask = [index for index,value in enumerate(a) if value in b.tolist()]
```

This iterates over every element in a, gets their index and values, and if the value is inside b, then gets the index.

Comment: I didn't want to get the value with index in b. What I want to do is get the index of the element whose value in b.

Comment: Updated the answer. I must have misunderstood your question.